# How can I fix the dark corners on the rear LCD of my Nikon D7000?

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting, nikon-d7000, lcd

I have a Nikon D7000. The rear LCD is showing some dark shadows. All four corners have this dark shadow but the shadows on upper and lower corners on the right side of the LCD is bigger. At first I thought it's a lens issue then I changed the lens and it's the same. Live view is pretty alarming with these corner patches.

My images are not affected by this dark shadow. I even tried removing the hood/filter. What could be the reason behind this problem and is there any way to solve this?  If anyone has faced the same issue, is there any solution or advice??

[image: dark corners/vignetting on rear lcd, sample photo]

Comment: may i know if you have found the problem and solution? My DSLR 3100 also having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Viewfinder "vignetting"/"tunnel view"

My vote is that the type of screen on the back of the camera is the culprit causing the darker corners of the view. The size of the screen is large and the angle of view of the corners is more oblique than through the centre, which appears brightest. The corners are darker due to increased corner illumination "falloff" due to the screen anti-reflection finish. I also note that the view of screen is a trapezoid so the shot is not perpendicular to the VF.

Here's how to verify, or rule out my take (!) on this:

If it's caused by the viewfinder screen, changing the angle of your view of the screen should change the appearance of the corners somewhat. For example, with the camera view fixed on an evenly illuminated wall, say, move your head upward and to the left. That should make the UL corner appear a bit lighter. Moving your head in the opposite direction would darken that corner.

The FIX is to hold the camera a bit further from your eye and look at your viewfinder screen square-on. That might not fix the corners; but, it may reduce the problem.

Some viewfinder screens show this darkening at the corners. It was most pronounced with deeply etched ground-glass screens in early "view" cameras and some 35mm cameras.

Comment: Could also try increasing the illumination level of the backlight for the LCD to see if that has an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Check your LCD brightness.  LCD screens include a polarization filter and may cause issues like this if the display is not bright enough (or if you are using a secondary polarizer like sunglasses or a filter on a camera.)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same vignetting problem (dark shadow in the lower left corner) with my D7000 bought in 2011.  As I was getting ready to send the camera in for repair, I called the local camera shop, and they asked me to first check the lens cap or cover saying the plastic there can get twisted and cause this to happen sometimes.  Sure enough part of the lens cover threading had chipped off in my camera and that's what was causing the shadow. Hope this helps.

Comment: But OP said this happens with multiple lenses, and the effect is ONLY visible on the LCD, not in any images taken. So it is not an issue with anything in the optical path.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a common case of lens vignetting. Here is a link to help you do some further research on understanding what causes this issue. https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14467/~/what-is-vignetting%3F

Comment: It looks like lens vignetting, but 1) doesn't affect final image, 2) happens with multiple lenses, 3) happens with lens hood removed?

Comment: The giveaway here is that the text overlay in the corners is also darkened. There's no way lens vignetting can account for screen text being darkened.

Comment: I didn't look that hard within the text. I would say maybe you have a faulty wire or something going wrong with your LCD screen. Is the camera new?