# Nikon d3000 lcd black corners

Tags: nikon, dslr, lcd, rear-lcd, nikon-d3000

I have recently acquired a used Nikon D3000 and I've noticed its lcd has dark corners. Seems to have a spotlight in the center of the lcd though it's not affecting the actual image when opened in laptop. I just want to know what's causing this as this might be an issue that can affect other parts of the unit in the future. I've aso looked around the settings for possible configuration but can't find any and also can't find a related thread over the internet.

Please see pic below.

[image: nikon d3000 lcd black corners]

Comment: Similar to this question - [Dark Corners in rear LCD of d7000](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76786/how-can-i-fix-the-dark-corners-on-the-rear-lcd-of-my-nikon-d7000) Possibly due to the screen illumination being too dim.

Comment: @BrendanBurkett i also tried setting lcd to highest contrast/brightness possible nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LCD's work on the principle of a white backlight and then filtering out the RGB colours as needed.  It appears the backlight of this camera's LCD is faulty and is not providing even illumination.

Your device needs to be repaired, Nikon can do it (though this option can be expensive), otherwise there are local repair shops who can take care of it for you, local camera shops usually have a relationship with someone or can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! The prob is I cant have it checked coz the local repair shops here are a bit far, around 3-4hrs away. Haha! But I guess I have no choice

Comment: Yup - if you can't do the drive, many repair shops will accept your camera by post and ship it back to you.  Would be cheaper than the time/cost of taking yourself to a shop where they're unlikely to look at it "while u wait" or even onsite.

Comment: I guess that's the best option aside from not having it repaired anymore as it doesn't affect the output anyways haha

Comment: Well, there's that or it seems like a good excuse to buy a new camera to me!  :)

Comment: Hahaha! Buying a new one isnt an option for me as it's expensive for someone like me plus I'm a newbie to dslr's. Im more of a phone photog guy.